# Can I split jQuery into two files?

Tags: jquery

As you know, the max MTU for TCP is 1500. The iPhone doesn't cache files bigger than 25kb.

Has anybody tried to split jQuery into two separate files?

[image]

jQuery 1.5.2 is 29.1kb. How can I split jQuery 1.5.2 into two files?

I have two files:

- jquery1.js ~15kb
- jquery2.js ~15kb

File will be cached on iPhone. Page will be open faster - 156ms

---

OK i move some function 'jquery.extend to external file 
just put eval();

asd = 'code'; -- neede remove white spaces escape ' " new lines by eq yuicompressor.jar

Comment: Isn't this what [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) is there for?

Comment: An extra HTTP request is always slower than loading a bigger file. Unless you only want the website to be used by Mobile users, I would suggest not splitting up the file.

Comment: @Pekka, doesn't jQuery mobile require jQuery? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Application Cache. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#manifests

You can save/cache all static files to disk regardless of size (up to 5MB without issue). If jQuery is all you are worried about:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# List of all resources required by this project

/script/path/to/jquery/jquery.js


NETWORK:
*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the code, look for instances of 'jquery.extend'. These should be able to be split off into individual files.